# Date picture format conversion

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a date field as 31-12-9999.

Whenever I try to pass this date to a proprocedure, it throws the Date Picture conversion error.

I have done the following-

Tried converting to 31-12-2999 and passed it into procedure, it is working

When I choose  select 31-12-9999 from dual,then it gives correct value.

So how to correct this?

Comment: Does the procedure require a date,  or a string? Have you tried `to_date('31-12-9999','dd-mm-yyyy')`

Answer (score 1):

> When I choose select 31-12-9999 from dual,then it gives correct value.

Because you are selecting the string literal and not date. To convert it into DATE, you must always explicitly mention the proper FORMAT MASK to convert into date.

Make sure the procedure's IN parameter is DATE data type, pass the value as

```
to_date('31-12-9999','dd-mm-yyyy')
```